# Nginx with separate Nodejs and Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, nginx, passenger

so I'm trying to set up a temporary second site on a VPS which is built on NodeJS. The VPS already runs the main site, which is a rails app, which is accessed via passenger.

My configuration looks like this:

```
#user  root;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/passenger-4.0.53;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    client_max_body_size 65m;

    server {    
      listen 80;
      server_name site-one.com; 
      passenger_enabled on;     
      root /home/user/Site-One/public;
    }

    server {
      listen 80;

      server_name site-two.com;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;             
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }
   }

}
```

Some other information:

- Both apps are on the same VPS, meaning same IP.
- Both apps have their own domain as in app-one.com and app-two.com
- Right now, when I try to access site-two.com, it directs me to site-one.com.

What could be my issue?

Comment: Have you restarted nginx?

Comment: Late reply, but oddly enough, this was basically my issue. I had to stop nginx, then start it as root. Makes sense, not sure why I didn't think of it at first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You said `app-(one|two).com` in part of your question, and you're showing `site-(one|two).com` elsewhere and in your config.  Probably just a typo, **but...**

Are you sure that the right hostnames are in your nginx config?  Including any `www.` prefix that you might be using?  Because if the `server-name` is incorrect (ie. not found) then nginx will route your request to the first server in your config which could explain the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score -1):

Move the

```
listen 80;
```

from server{} level to http{} level

Comment: nginx will not even start. `listen` could be declared only in server block http://nginx.org/r/listen